# Tailwind classes not working when creating dynamic pages with gatsby-node

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, gatsby, postcss

I am creating dynamic pages with gatsby-node. My templates reside in `templates/` directory. I am unable to use tailwind classes for templates unless they are used in some other components or pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed - Need to add `"./src/templates/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",` in content array in tailwind.config.js.